# How to turn on a ballofix / ball valve?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, kitchens, valve

When I turned the valve off, it was as if it made a small click, as if it had reached a locking position.

Now I can't turn it on again.

I have one other just like this one, and that one can I turn on and off without problems.

Are there some trick to know in order to turn on a valve this this?

[image: Picture of the valve I can't turn on again]

Comment: @Niall C: Do you pull out at the same time?

Comment: @Niall C: You are a life saver. It worked =) It was as if the force had to come in a specific angle in order to it to turn. If you copy/paste your answer then I will accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider switching to a ball lever valve if this remains a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have one that does the same thing; it just needs a **little** more twisting force to get it past that "locked" position.  I've always been able to do it by hand, no tools required.